# Animation in windows store app using c#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have an usercontrol in a grid that i want to reposition 400 pixels with an animation.
I can use the following code to reposition it without animation.

`ucChat.Margin = new Thickness(0, -400, 0, 0);`

i try to use the following code to animate it but i get an exception

```
DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500));
da.From = 0;
da.To = -400;

Storyboard st = new Storyboard();
Storyboard.SetTarget(da, ucChat);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, "ucChat.Margin.Top");
st.Children.Add(da);

st.Begin();
```

An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Regenwormen.exe but was not handled in user code
WinRT information: Cannot resolve TargetProperty ucChat.Margin.Top on specified object.

Does anyone have an idea how i can solve this or what animation i need to use ? (thicknessanimation doesn't excists in windows store apps)

Comment: did you try to write the storyboard in XAML? There you get Intellisense support for problems like this. You can Access Storyboards in the Resources via the Resources Collection or the FindRessource Method.